# Android get google token id

Tags: android, google-api, access-token

I have been following these two tutorials:
`https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in`
`https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth`

I managed to integrate google login system into my android application but when I try to get token id I am get null.

When I try to use following code:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
    .build();
```

I get fail on user log in. When I call:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

I am unable to retrieve token.

I tried to merge this code to have:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .build();
```

but without any success.

Here is my code:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

 // [START onActivityResult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
// [END onActivityResult]

// [START handleSignInResult]
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        mStatusTextView.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, acct.getDisplayName()));
        updateUI(true);

        String idToken = acct.getIdToken();
        if (idToken != null) {
            Log.d("TOKEN", idToken);
        } else {
            Log.d("TOKEN", "CHUUUUUUJ WIELKI!");
        }
    } else {
        // Signed out, show unauthenticated UI.
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111978/why-is-requestidtoken-returning-null

Comment: Above answer is correct! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear .Move ahead .

Comment: Could you please help me with my issue, i spend some days trying to solve it... I use the same code, but when i retrive `tokenId` from google api, i get a `String tokenId = <857 chars>`... ?? If i tryed to validate it `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token= <857 chars response>`  i all the get 'error_description": "Invalid Value' ... How are you make a validation of your response? Are you also get `String tokenId = <857 chars>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Google APIs use the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authentication and
>   authorization. Google supports common OAuth 2.0 scenarios such as
>   those for web server, installed, and client-side applications.
>
> To begin, obtain OAuth 2.0 client credentials from the Google
>   Developers Console. Then your client application requests an access
>   token from the Google Authorization Server, extracts a token from the
>   response, and sends the token to the Google API that you want to
>   access. For an interactive demonstration of using OAuth 2.0 with
>   Google (including the option to use your own client credentials),
>   experiment with the OAuth 2.0 Playground.

For details Go Through **[requestIdToken returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111978/why-is-requestidtoken-returning-null)**

Comment: Could you please help me with my issue, i spend some days trying to solve it... I use the same code, but when i retrive `tokenId` from google api, i get a `String tokenId = <857 chars>`... ?? If i tryed to validate it `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token= <857 chars response>`  i all the get 'error_description": "Invalid Value' ... How are you make a validation of your response? Are you also get `String tokenId = <857 chars>`?

Comment: Hi Aleksey! I would start with checking if you have correct credentails within your developer console (SHA-1 fingerprint) and double check if you put details from developer console inside your code. Read more here `http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/` and here: `https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating`