# Developer error Authenticate Gmail signin Android - Exception 10

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-signin

I want to authenticate gmail login with backend server, So I came across this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth

Gmail signin option,

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

here I am requesting for `requestIdToken`.

`server_client_id` is Web application auth id generated from google developer console.
This works fine when I request only email in GoogleSignInOptions, But when I request for IdToken it is giving **developer error**

Tried below links, but still developer error only.

[Error 12501 authenticating with google sign-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846801/error-12501-authenticating-with-google-sign-in)

[why is requestIdToken returning null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111978/why-is-requestidtoken-returning-null)

Comment: Check this link, i think its a configuration error on your part. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37273145/error-statusstatuscode-developer-error-resolution-null

Answer (score 0):

It hapens when your console app SHA mismaches with project SHA

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/360#issuecomment-381648685

make sure the web `client ID` (if you're using it) belongs to the same project where you registered your package name and `SHA1`.