# Android GoogleSignInOptions Error code: 12500 on requestIdToken With valid serverClientId

Tags: android, google-signin

Android GoogleSignInOptions Error code: 12500 on requestIdToken With valid serverClientId

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.google_server_client_id))               
                .build();
```

it returns fail with code: 12500

```
gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()              
                .build();
```

this code works but idToken is null

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099208/google-sign-in-requestidtoken-returns-null/34146759#34146759 to see if it can help

Comment: thanks for the help., i still have the problem even when i use Webapplication type clientID.

Comment: So, try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846801/error-12501-authenticating-with-google-sign-in

Comment: thanks., but that didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

use "Web application" type Client Id, instead of "Android" type Client Id.

find solved for me
[Google Sign-In requestIdToken returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099208/google-sign-in-requestidtoken-returns-null/34146759#34146759)