# requestIdToken in GoogleSignInOptions gets null pointer exception

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I'm trying to add google sign in to my app using these instructions: 
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

In my signInActivity I'm getting a null pointer exception on requestIdToken()
in the command

```
mSignInOpt = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                     .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                     .build();
```

When I use this command without requestIdToken(), it is working perfectly and I'm getting user's name,email etc. in onActivityResult callback, but the token is null.

I made sure that both OAuth 2.0 client IDs in my web console match the ones I use in my app:

[image: OAuth 2.0 client IDs in my web console]

I also downloaded google-services.json that the new changes and copied it to my "mobile" folder of the project.

[image: google-services.json I downloaded from firebase console]

I've tried all the answers in the links below but nothing solved my problem.

Please Help!

Links:

1. [Google Sign-In requestIdToken returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099208/google-sign-in-requestidtoken-returns-null)
2. [New Google sign in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583326/new-google-sign-in-android)
3. [Error 12501 authenticating with google sign-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846801/error-12501-authenticating-with-google-sign-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
mSignInOpt = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                     .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                     .build();
```

was outside of the `OnCreate()` method, meaning mSignInOpt is a global member for that activity and it is configured when activity is created.

For some reason `.requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))` cannot be called in that case ( without requestIdToken() it works fine ).

To fix the error,  I moved  those few lines of code into `OnCreate()` method
and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have enough rep for a comment but can you do something like

```
mSignInOpt = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                 .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                 .requestEmail()
                 .build();
```

and it gives a valid response? or does it not work at all?

I'd try looking at [this](https://github.com/lmoroney/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/IdTokenActivity.java) for more help.

Comment: I tried that. I get the same exception on .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))

Comment: GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestProfile()
                .requestEmail()
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .build();

This is how i added and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

```
   googleSignInButton = findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

Comment: Instructions and explanations are equally part of a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

You missing this line in build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'